# MS-ACCESS VBA How to call a public function by formname and controlnames

Tags: forms, function, ms-access

I have a public function that just copy the value from a textbox to another.

```
Public Function ChangeDocType(frmName As Form, ctrlSourceName As control, ctrlDestName As control)
frmName.ctrlDestName.value = frmName.ctrlSourceName.value
End Function
```

I'm calling this function in a form like this but doesn't work..help

```
ChangeDocType Me, Me.Source.Name, Me.Dest.Name
```

Comment: Is form used as subform? I have never needed to pass form and control objects. I would pass names as strings. `Forms(frmName).Controls(ctrlDestName) = Forms(frmName).Controls(ctrlSourceName)`

Comment: Either way, think I would not pass source control, just its value via Variant data type variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work (I made it a Sub but Function would work):

`ChangeDocType Me, Me.Source, Me.Dest`

```
Public Sub ChangeDocType(frmName As Form, ctrlSourceName As Control, ctrlDestName As Control)
frmName(ctrlDestName.Name) = frmName(ctrlSourceName.Name)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your arguments' names are confusing, as you don't pass the names of the controls but the controls themselves. Also, when doing so, the form is of no use. Further, as June7, I would use a subprocedure, thus:

```vb
Public Sub ChangeDocType(Source As Control, Destination As Control)

    Destination.Value = Source.Value

End Sub
```

To be called:

```
ChangeDocType Me!Source, Me!Destination
```

If you wish to pass the *names* of the controls, the form is needed, here by its name as well:

```vb
Public Sub ChangeDocType(FormName As String, SourceName As String, DestinationName As String)

    Forms(FormName).Controls(DestinationName).Value = Forms(FormName).Controls(SourceName).Value

End Sub
```

To be called:

```
ChangeDocType Me.Name, Me!SourceControl.Name, Me!DestinationControl.Name
```